# How can I record a speech synthesizer reading a webpage?

Tags: linux, audio-recording, text-to-speech

I would like to have a speech synthesizer that can convert HTML text to speech recorded in a standard audiobook format.

I would prefer to do this under Linux, but can use Windows if need be.

Comment: What distro of Linux, Ubuntu? You could use one of these and feed it input from a .txt file (copy/paste the text from the website in question to the .txt file): https://askubuntu.com/questions/501910/how-to-text-to-speech-output-using-command-line

Comment: ...then you could use this to capture the audio: https://askubuntu.com/questions/229352/how-to-record-output-to-speakers